How to connect MQ with load runner
I am trying to connect load runner to IBM.
Tried many blogs but in vain.
Can someone please help step by step process to connect load runner to IBM MQ
Want to connect load runner to IBM MQ.
Step by step procedure or any leads would help.

What error are you getting?  Try pasting the following into the stackoverflow search to get all questions tagged for both IBM MQ and load runner: [loadrunner] [ibm-mq]

What details were provided by your MQ Admin on how to connect to the queue manager?   How you configure things would be based on how the queue manager is configured.  How to troubleshoot would be based on your configuration and the error you are receiving.  You have provide almost no details,  how can you expect someone to answer you?

@JoshMc Please suggest im looking for steps how to connect load runner to mq

Sine you have jmeter in your question title and tags here is JMeter solution:

Download com.ibm.mq.allclient jar and drop it to JMeter Classpath
Restart JMeter to pick up the .jar
Add JSR223 Sampler to your Test Plan
Add Groovy code implementing your test scenario into the JSR223 Sampler's "Script" area

Example code snippets can be found i.e. in Write and run your first IBM MQ JMS application article, just in case I copy it here:
/*
 * (c) Copyright IBM Corporation 2018
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.ibm.mq.samples.jms;

import java.io.Console;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSConsumer;
import javax.jms.JMSContext;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.JMSProducer;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsConnectionFactory;
import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsFactoryFactory;
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants;

/**
 * A minimal and simple application for Point-to-point messaging.
 *
 * Application makes use of fixed literals, any customisations will require
 * re-compilation of this source file. Application assumes that the named queue
 * is empty prior to a run.
 *
 * Notes:
 *
 * API type: JMS API (v2.0, simplified domain)
 *
 * Messaging domain: Point-to-point
 *
 * Provider type: IBM MQ
 *
 * Connection mode: Client connection
 *
 * JNDI in use: No
 *
 */
public class JmsPutGet {

    // System exit status value (assume unset value to be 1)
    private static int status = 1;

    // Create variables for the connection to MQ
    private static final String HOST = "_YOUR_HOSTNAME_"; // Host name or IP address
    private static final int PORT = 1414; // Listener port for your queue manager
    private static final String CHANNEL = "DEV.APP.SVRCONN"; // Channel name
    private static final String QMGR = "QM1"; // Queue manager name
    private static final String APP_USER = "app"; // User name that application uses to connect to MQ
    private static final String APP_PASSWORD = "_APP_PASSWORD_"; // Password that the application uses to connect to MQ
    private static final String QUEUE_NAME = "DEV.QUEUE.1"; // Queue that the application uses to put and get messages to and from


    /**
     * Main method
     *
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Sanity check main() arguments and warn user
        if (args.length > 0) {
            System.out.println("\n!!!! WARNING: You have provided arguments to the Java main() function. JVM arguments (such as -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore) must be passed before the main class or .jar you wish to run.\n\n");
            Console c = System.console();
            System.out.println("Press the Enter key to continue");
            c.readLine();
        }

        // Variables
        JMSContext context = null;
        Destination destination = null;
        JMSProducer producer = null;
        JMSConsumer consumer = null;



        try {
            // Create a connection factory
            JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
            JmsConnectionFactory cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();

            // Set the properties
            cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, HOST);
            cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, PORT);
            cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, CHANNEL);
            cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, QMGR);
            cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_APPLICATIONNAME, "JmsPutGet (JMS)");
            cf.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, true);
            cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, APP_USER);
            cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, APP_PASSWORD);
            //cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_SSL_CIPHER_SUITE, "*TLS12ORHIGHER");

            // Create JMS objects
            context = cf.createContext();
            destination = context.createQueue("queue:///" + QUEUE_NAME);

            long uniqueNumber = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000;
            TextMessage message = context.createTextMessage("Your lucky number today is " + uniqueNumber);

            producer = context.createProducer();
            producer.send(destination, message);
            System.out.println("Sent message:\n" + message);

            consumer = context.createConsumer(destination); // autoclosable
            String receivedMessage = consumer.receiveBody(String.class, 15000); // in ms or 15 seconds

            System.out.println("\nReceived message:\n" + receivedMessage);

            context.close();

            recordSuccess();
        } catch (JMSException jmsex) {
            recordFailure(jmsex);
        }

        System.exit(status);

    } // end main()

    /**
     * Record this run as successful.
     */
    private static void recordSuccess() {
        System.out.println("SUCCESS");
        status = 0;
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Record this run as failure.
     *
     * @param ex
     */
    private static void recordFailure(Exception ex) {
        if (ex != null) {
            if (ex instanceof JMSException) {
                processJMSException((JMSException) ex);
            } else {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("FAILURE");
        status = -1;
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Process a JMSException and any associated inner exceptions.
     *
     * @param jmsex
     */
    private static void processJMSException(JMSException jmsex) {
        System.out.println(jmsex);
        Throwable innerException = jmsex.getLinkedException();
        if (innerException != null) {
            System.out.println("Inner exception(s):");
        }
        while (innerException != null) {
            System.out.println(innerException);
            innerException = innerException.getCause();
        }
        return;
    }

}

JMeter-specific examples can be found in IBM MQ Tutorial: Learn How to Testing With JMeter article

There is an MQ protocol add-in for Loadrunner.   You can head that path.   Before the MQ Protocol add on was available (20++ years ago) you had a couple of paths that are still open to you

Winsock, if recording the MQ client
Any template user that supports the MQ interface to leverage direct API calls to the MQ client libraries.

I prefer Winsock.   I will readily admit that path is not for everyone.   One of my colleagues described it once as picking fly scat out of ground pepper - tedious, but in the end very rewarding.

Hi James, I never used Winsock. Can you please share steps if you have which I can use to connect load runner to IBM MQ

In this order, (1) Read the winsock documentation (2) If you have access to the flightsock application for demo and training purposes, experiment with that (3) Record your MQ application us9ing Winsock (4) Use the skills developed to manipulate the script to address dynamic items and user inputs.

Somthing you need to confirm immediately is whether you even have the license to use the protocol you have selected.   It does you no good if you record protocol X and you are not licensed for it.
